# How can I divide 2 series in Grafana with CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, grafana

I have 2 series in Grafana coming from CloudWatch (sum of 200s and sum of 400s). I would like to divide one of them by the other one but the function divideSeries is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudwatch does not support operations on multiple series.

Comment: That used to be true, but is no longer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html